# How do I change app icon in Recents Screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I managed to change the icon except on the recents screen/recent apps part

[image: Recents screen]

Comment: just change your ic_launcher icon in your mipmap

Comment: So you want to change app icon for specific case or permanently? Also if you can highlight what you mean by background ?

Answer (score 0):

Goto to your manifest file and here you can change your icon with the desired one.

```
android:icon="@mipmap/iconthermometer"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/iconthermometer"
```

you can also assign your drawable icon to these attribute

Comment: I changed this, reinstalled the app, emulator still doesn't update

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed your icon in correct way, the icon in recents screen should have changed too.
You can change your app icon by **res > New > Image Asset**

You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts98gL1JCQU) as a guide.

But if you have done it the correct way but still the icon did not get changed, try rebooting your phone and/or reinstalling the app.

Comment: I still see the default android icon after re-installing the app.

Comment: @quantumpotato have you tried rebooting your phone?

Comment: Rebooting the phone fixed the issue for me. Weird bug though. Google should probably look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried Everything try **Rebooting your phone and** **Rebuilding** **the project** , It was the solution for me.